# I want to restrict users from entering number ending with 5

Tags: javascript, html, forms, text

Here is text field.I want users to only enter value like 210,220,230,... and restrict from entering something like 215,225,...

I am looking for suggetions.I don't have much knowledge of javascript.

Comment: What have you tried so far? put some code so we can have a better understand

Comment: <input name="cgiftcardq"  class="text_field" id="cgiftcardq"
                                                   size="3" autocomplete="off" type="text "/>

Comment: I am looking for suggetions.I don't have much knowledge of javascript.

Comment: Include all relevant code **in your question**, not in the comments.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please review the FAQ on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure you include the relevant information needed to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to prevent strings that end in '5':

```
 document.getElementById("input").onblur = checkEND;

    function checkEND() {
      let firstValue = event.currentTarget.value;
      if(firstValue.endsWith('5')){
       warnUser()
      }
    }
```

This won't validate that the string is a valid number though.

Comment: add some description what is your solution about

Answer (score 0):

```js
function testInput() {
    var key = window.event.keyCode;
    var x = document.getElementById('textarea').value
    var y = document.getElementById('textarea2').value
    var z = parseInt(x, 10);
    if (z+10 == y) {
       document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "valid";
       } else {
       document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "invalid";
       }
}
```

```html
<textarea maxlength="3" id="textarea">5</textarea>
<textarea maxlength="3" id="textarea2">15</textarea>
<button onclick="testInput()">Test Input</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

The first input is your first number, the second is your second number.
*See Comments If Your Wondering Why This Doesn't Answer His OG Question*

Comment: This block all fives. But OP wants _number ending with 5_

Comment: Is there a possible way that user can only enter the number incremnt of 10 like 210,220,230 ,.....??

Comment: So do you want the users input to be a list of numbers that all have the same increment?

Answer (score 0):

You can experiment with the `setCustomValidity()` of `input` elements (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) from an `onblur`, `onchange` or `oninput` handler. If you are not satisfied with the value, set an error message, and an empty string otherwise. As long as the error message is set to non-empty, it is displayed and the form refuses to submit:

```js
function check5() {
  cgiftcardq.setCustomValidity(cgiftcardq.value.endsWith('5')?"Nope, it can not end with 5":"");
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="cgiftcardq" class="text_field" id="cgiftcardq" size="3" autocomplete="off" type="text" onblur="check5()">
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

(StackOverflow snippets interfere with form submission - probably as part of security -, so successful submission just makes the form disappear)

---

As `setCustomValidity()` does not work everywhere (according to the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Browser_compatibility), it will not work on non-Andorid mobiles), classic "budget" solution may be mentioned too: you can simply disable the send button as long as you are not satisfied with the input:

```js
function check5() {
  if(cgiftcardq.value.endsWith('5')){
    send.disabled=true;
    message.innerHTML="Nope, it can not end with 5";
  } else {
    send.disabled=false;
    message.innerHTML="OK";
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="cgiftcardq" class="text_field" id="cgiftcardq" size="3" autocomplete="off" type="text" oninput="check5()">
  <input id="send" type="submit" value="Send" disabled>
</form>
<div id="message"></div>
```